# Types of scenarios implemented by companies for Performance test a System

Tags: web, e-commerce, jmeter, performance-testing, scenarios

As a newbie to JMeter, I have created some scenarios like some number of users are logging in to the system, sending some HTTP Request, Requests are looped, etc.

I would like to know what are the real world scenarios implemented by Companies to Performance test their System using JMeter.

Consider a E-Commerce Website and what all scenarios they might consider to performance test their Website?

Comment: for this,first you should read about what is performance testing and then about workload modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of performance testing is generating a real life load to the system simulating real users as close as possible. In regards to E-commerce system it would be something like:

- N users searching for some term
- M users browsing and navigating
- X users making purchases

To simulate different usage scenarios you can use different thread groups or set weight using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

To make your JMeter test looking more like a real browser add the following test elements to your test plan:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - to represent browser cookies, simulate different unique sessions and deal with cookie-based authentication
- [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) - to simulate browser cache. Browsers download embedded resources like images, scripts, styles, etc. but to it only once. Cache Manager replicates this behavior and also respects cache control headers.
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - to represent browser headers like User-Agent, Accept-Language and so on.

Also according to [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you need to "tell" JMeter to retrieve all embedded resources from pages and use concurrent thread pool from 3 to 5 threads for it. The best place to put this config in is [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).